# How To update google-cloud-dataflow running in app engine without clearing bigquery tables

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

I have a `google-cloud-dataflow` process running on the `App-engine`.
It listens to messages sent via `pubsub` and streams to `big-query`.

I updated my code and I am trying to rerun the app.

But I receive this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: BigQuery table is not empty
```

Is there anyway to update data flow without deleting the table?
Since my code might change quite often, and I do not want to delete data in the table.

Here is my code:

```
public class MyPipline {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BotPipline.class);
    private static String name;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<TableFieldSchema> fields = new ArrayList<>();
        fields.add(new TableFieldSchema().setName("a").setType("string"));
        fields.add(new TableFieldSchema().setName("b").setType("string"));
        fields.add(new TableFieldSchema().setName("c").setType("string"));
        TableSchema tableSchema = new TableSchema().setFields(fields);

        DataflowPipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.as(DataflowPipelineOptions.class);
        options.setRunner(BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner.class);
        options.setProject("my-data-analysis");
        options.setStagingLocation("gs://my-bucket/dataflow-jars");
        options.setStreaming(true);

        Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(options);

        PCollection<String> input = pipeline
                .apply(PubsubIO.Read.subscription(
                        "projects/my-data-analysis/subscriptions/myDataflowSub"));

        input.apply(ParDo.of(new DoFn<String, Void>() {

            @Override
            public void processElement(DoFn<String, Void>.ProcessContext c) throws Exception {
                LOG.info("json" + c.element());
            }

        }));
        String fileName = UUID.randomUUID().toString().replaceAll("-", "");


        input.apply(ParDo.of(new DoFn<String, String>() {
            @Override
            public void processElement(DoFn<String, String>.ProcessContext c) throws Exception {
                JSONObject firstJSONObject = new JSONObject(c.element());
                firstJSONObject.put("a", firstJSONObject.get("a").toString()+ "1000");
                c.output(firstJSONObject.toString());

            }

        }).named("update json")).apply(ParDo.of(new DoFn<String, TableRow>() {

            @Override
            public void processElement(DoFn<String, TableRow>.ProcessContext c) throws Exception {
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(c.element());
                TableRow row = new TableRow().set("a", json.get("a")).set("b", json.get("b")).set("c", json.get("c"));
                c.output(row);
            }

        }).named("convert json to table row"))
                .apply(BigQueryIO.Write.to("my-data-analysis:mydataset.mytable").withSchema(tableSchema)
        );

        pipeline.run();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify `withWriteDisposition` on your `BigQueryIO.Write` - see documentation [of the method](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/io/BigQueryIO.Write.html#withWriteDisposition-com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.io.BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition-) and [of its argument](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/io/BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition). Depending on your requirements, you need either `WRITE_TRUNCATE` or `WRITE_APPEND`.